# Get stack trace at the end of any webpage browse

Tags: php, apache

I found this two nice things from stackoverflow that prints the stack trace.

```
debug_print_backtrace();

// or

$e = new Exception;
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
```

But this only prints the traces whenever I call it(means only prints from a particular function). My intention is to have this stack trace whenever any page is browsed from my application.

For example, when I browse the `/product` page from my application I want the functions which are called for this action. Similarly for other pages. More precisely to have the traces at the end of the Action. I need this because the number of function calls vary based on parameter and database value.

Is there any way to use the above code from one place so that it will reflect from everywhere when the action is completed? Or any configuration at `apache` will do it for me? Or any alternate methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex problem since PHP does not provide a functionality to list all the functions calls for a given script. You could try logging all the functions calls using either [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind/wiki) but keep in mind that you won't have function parameters. If that is not enough you could implement a logging function, but it would need to be included in every function call...

Please read further about the application tracing with xdebug: http://devzone.zend.com/1135/tracing-php-applications-with-xdebug/